# High White blood cell count without fever

Tags: infection

Is it possible / likely that a critically ill patient with a blood infection and high white blood cell count of 45,000 could be *without* fever?

Thanks.

Comment: There are various factors that would lead someone who is severely ill, even septic, to not develop a fever.  This question lacks demonstration of the background research, which is a recommendation for thsi site, and may lead to being closed. Please check out some of our how-to's and meta.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. As @DoctorWhom pointed out, for [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?